# Can a RAID be a Time Machine backup?

Tags: time-machine, raid

If I configure a large external drive as a RAID, can TimeMachine use it for backups?

I see it can [use a Drobo](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/95229/can-time-machine-be-used-as-a-drobo-system), but can it use even a "home-brewed" RAID?

Comment: How would it be connected to MacOS? Is this "home-brewed" RAID capable of network sharing via SMB?

Comment: A great number of commercial NAS devices allow you do exactly that, I have a QNAS, it works a treat. They have software in them that announces to any macOS computer that it is capable of being backed up to via Time Machine, so yes. If your external RAID appears as a single drive to macOS then when you plug it in, it will likely ask if you want to use it as a Time Machine backup.

Comment: It would be on an older iMac by USB and auto-mounted on the MacBook.  With an Airport between, if I can make that work.  I got the Airport and the iMac at a thrift store.  iMac is at the latest OS it can handle.  Airport is probably not up-to-date, but I have to rearrange the room and run a cat 5 cable before I can start setting things up.  It won't have the software you mentioned unless I can find it somewhere and install it after formatting the device.

Comment: So you have a Mac and a RAID? It is time to get them connected and try to make Time Machine backup!

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement, but first I have to create the beast.